# Why is my custom sidebar always open on the widgets screen in Admin?

Tags: sidebar, register-sidebar

I've created a custom sidebar with this code in my theme's functions.php:

```
register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => __('Article - Below Content'),
        'id' => 'zg-article-footer',
        'description' => 'Use this sidebar to place widgets that will appear directly underneath the Article'
    ));
```

When I navigate to Appearance > Widgets in my Admin, this sidebar is always the first one on the top of my list of sidebars, and it's always "open" (that is, you can see the description and the list of widgets attached to it). None of my other sidebars are open, and WP Admin doesn't seem to remember my last-opened sidebar.

Is there an argument I should use when registering the sidebar that will tell it to default to closed? Or is there an option somewhere else entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is default behavior. I believe that sidebars are listed by ID in `Dashboard -> Appearance -> Widgets`, and that the sidebar with ID `0` is always open in the default view.

Comment: Interesting. But are you then supposed to use numeric IDs for sidebars? I would have thought that could be a conflict risk... my id is a unique identifier that should not collide with any others. Is there a better alternative?

Comment: The issue isn't with your sidebar's ID, *per se*, but rather that WordPress *always* displays the *first* sidebar as *open*, and all other sidebars as *closed*.